# Django Rest Framework does not output filtered Querysets

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using a DRF ViewSet to search for a name, but only partial text. The problem is i use `get_queryset` to filter data out of DB with `icontains`:

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.CustomerSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    lookup_field = 'full_name'

    def get_queryset(self):

        if self.kwargs:
            return models.Customer.objects.filter(full_name__icontains=self.kwargs['full_name'])
        else:
            return models.Customer.objects.all()
```

The view sends me a `404 error`, but when i print it in the terminal it shows existing data.

Comment: Did you debug and confirm that your  `if self.kwargs` statement is true, and that the queryset actually return what you expect?

Comment: Yes, i did and it is true even when is empty (i already fixed that). The problem is the view is not serializing the Model, but when i dump it to the terminal it shows the data.

Comment: Could your serializer be losing the data somehow?  And, um, you're definitely accessing the correct URL right?

Comment: What does the urls.py look like ? What does the request you perform look like ?

Comment: Add your `urls.py` content and actual URL you're calling would help others to better understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`api/views.py`

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter

class SearchViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CustomerSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['full_name']
```

### URL

- `/api/customers/<pk>` where pk is the unique id of `Customer`
- `/api/customers/?search=<full_name>` where `full_name` is the search query

So, i can retrieve data from `id` and search for a customer by its name. But we can add fields to `search_fields` if we want to look for information in another fields, like `search_fields = ['full_name', 'address']`. `/api/customers/?search=some address` will search in `address` field too.